# How to measure DC current with a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32f4, current-sensing

I have a project where I need to measure DC currents in the range of 0-150 A. I am using an STM32F446RE MCU. I can't use the solution where I convert current to voltage using resistors and reading them using the ADC pin of my MCU. I have found some components like the ACS712 Current Sensor that internally converts current (0-30 A) into a voltage, which I could later read using my MCU, but I can only find cases where they use a PIC MCU. For example: https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/digital-ammeter-circuit-using-pic16f877a-acs712 .

What changes would I need to do the make this work on my MCU?. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you use a shunt resistor? What resolution do you need?

Comment: I could use a Shunt resistor if I was only measuring currents from 0-5A.Because I need to measure from 0 to 150 A the power rating of the resistors would need to be very high while the value of Ohm would need to be low.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's 150 A, you can still use a shunt, it would just have to be (very) high powered.

Comment: The ACS712 is a Hall effect current sensor, something like that is probably your best bet.

Comment: Yes, hall effect is the way to go since it's isolated.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to use the ADC on the STM32F446RE?

Comment: I know how to use the Adc , but i need i way to convert the current into voltage to read on the MCU

Comment: Google hall sensor 150A.

Comment: You can measure 150A with a shunt resistor and it only needs to be 5W

Answer (score 0):

The ASC712 output range is 0 to 5V, the STM32 ADC pins accept 0 to 3.3V*, therefore you need a [Voltage Divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnSsqo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using the [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#Resistive_divider) gives
$$V_{ADC} = \frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}} \cdot VI_{OUT} = \frac{3000\Omega}{2000\Omega+3000\Omega} \cdot 5V=3V$$

which is accepted by the ADC input pin.

* If the STM32 supply voltage is less than 3V, adjust the resistor values to match it.

Comment: Does the ASC712 accept currents from 0 to 150 A?

Comment: I found this current transdutor , Hais 50-P, that has a wide current range -150 to 150A  . Do you think i can use this one in the place of the ACS712?